# Julia: Visualize images saved in csv form

Tags: csv, imageview, julia

What would be the best way of visualizing images saved in .csv format?

The following doesn't work:

```
using CSV, ImageView
data = CSV.read("myfile.csv");
imshow(data)
```

This is the error:

```
MethodError: no method matching pixelspacing(::DataFrames.DataFrame)
Closest candidates are:
  pixelspacing(!Matched::MappedArrays.AbstractMultiMappedArray) at /Users/xxx/.julia/packages/ImageCore/yKxN6/src/traits.jl:63
  pixelspacing(!Matched::MappedArrays.AbstractMappedArray) at /Users/xxx/.julia/packages/ImageCore/yKxN6/src/traits.jl:62
  pixelspacing(!Matched::OffsetArrays.OffsetArray) at /Users/xxx/.julia/packages/ImageCore/yKxN6/src/traits.jl:67
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] imshow(::Any, ::Reactive.Signal{GtkReactive.ZoomRegion{RoundingIntegers.RInt64}}, ::ImageView.SliceData, ::Any; name::Any, aspect::Any) at /Users/xxx/.julia/packages/ImageView/sCn9Q/src/ImageView.jl:269
 [2] imshow(::Any; axes::Any, name::Any, aspect::Any) at /Users/xxx.julia/packages/ImageView/sCn9Q/src/ImageView.jl:260
 [3] imshow(::Any) at /Users/xxx/.julia/packages/ImageView/sCn9Q/src/ImageView.jl:259
 [4] top-level scope at In[5]:2
 [5] include_string(::Function, ::Module, ::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1091
```

Reference on [github](https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageView.jl/issues/241).

Comment: What do you mean by "image saved in CSV format"? CSV is used for tabular oriented data and this can be vizualised in many different ways depending on one's needs.

Comment: I am given a CSV file that contains pixel by pixel information of an image. Also, I know MATLAB is capable of visualizing this type of tabular data with imshow() function.

Comment: Please provide some sample data. One pixel is normally 3 bytes (RGB) so this is not clear how your data is encoded. Or your image is in gray scale? In both cases this is a one liner in Julia, but more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered at https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageView.jl/issues/241. Copying the answer here:

```
imshow(Matrix(data))
```

where `data` is your DataFrame. But CSV is a poor choice for images; [Netbpm](https://github.com/JuliaIO/Netpbm.jl) if you simply must use text-formatted images, otherwise binary would be recommended. Binary Netpbm are especially easy to write, if you have to write your own (e.g., if the images are coming from some language that doesn't support other file formats), otherwise PNG is typically a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Does the CSV file have a header line of names for its columns or is it just a delimited file full of text number values?

If the CSV file is actually in the form of a matrix of values, such that the values are the bytes of a 2D image, you may use DelimitedFiles -- see [readdlm() docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/DelimitedFiles/). Read the file with readdlm() into a matrix and see if ImageView can display the results.